# Laravel 5.3 form submit does nothing

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5.3

In my Laravel 5.3 form when i click submit button nothing happens, it does not redirecting me anywhere, just reloading same page.

My route looks like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

  Route::post('/delete-product', [

        'uses' => 'UserController@deleteProduct',
        'as' => 'delete.product',

    ]);
}
```

And my form:

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{{ route('delete.product') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
   <input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}">
   <input id="amount" type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" value="1"> 
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right list-element__btn btn-  edit" role="button">
      Delete
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: What does the `deleteProduct` function look like?

Comment: public function deleteProduct(Requests\ProductRequest $request){

        die;
        $product = Product::find($request->input('user_id'));
        $deleteAmount = $request->input('amount');
        $product->amount =- $deleteAmount;

        return redirect( route( 'welcome' ) );
    }

Comment: so as you can see it does'nt even get there

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out, it doesn't do anything cause of the request parameter that method accept: `Requests\ProductRequest $request` But still i don't know the reason why this is happening, any thoughts?

My controller method looks like this:

```
public function deleteProduct(Requests\ProductRequest $request){


        $product = Product::find($request->input('user_id'));
        $deleteAmount = $request->input('amount');
        $product->amount =- $deleteAmount;

        return redirect( route( 'welcome' ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For whom stupid like me, check your requested form data, it might fail the validated rules, so it will redirection back. In blade file you can dumb $errors vaiable to see the failed message.